# Strange characters in writing ascii code on Mac (C++ and Armadillo linear algebra library)

Tags: c++, ascii, armadillo

I am a Mac user. I implemented a program using the [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) linear algebra library. Using:

```
T.save("T.txt", raw_ascii); // this is a library function to save matrix into txt file
```

I was able to print the matrix T in T.txt file. It was successful on my Mac. The T.txt file eventually is loaded on MATLAB for the post-processing.

However, I copied the source codes to my friend's Mac and compiled. The txt file contains weird characters like:

```
 ˇˇ9.298452339097e-02 ˇ-1.343127536975e+00 ˇˇ3.188132564527e+01
 ˇˇ1.343127788111e+00 ˇˇ9.298420146411e-02 ˇ-1.630093163671e+01
```

and MATLAB fails to read the txt file.

Why does this happen? These computers are both Macs (maybe different models). Is it because of the different compilers? I did this using Xcode. Is there a way to specify some desired ASCII character set?

** ASIDE update: Thanks for all who replied. I checked the diskio::save_raw_ascii() inside the library. It uses

```
diskio::save_raw_ascii(...blah blah..., std::ostream& f)
f.put(' ');
```

I guess it does not have any problems, right? I think I need to test with this simple code on my friend's computer.

Comment: Did you open the file and save it with some other text editor?

Comment: Try to open it with a hex editor and find the value corresponding to the weird characters

Comment: The `ˇ` marks appear (based on copy/paste) to be U+02C7 (CARON). Maybe they are used as field delimiters, so there are two empty fields at the start of the line, and another empty field in each other line.  Alternatively, you have two of those marks before a positive number and one before a negative number.  It looks as though you will need to study how to tweak the options to the `save` function.  Is it C or Objective-C (or C++), incidentally?  The `T.save` notation is not invalid in C, but it is unusual.  It is normal in Objective-C and C++.

Comment: This is character code `0xFF` (255) in Mac OS RomanEncoding. It looks like padding of some kind. Does that give you a clue of where to look for?

Comment: The source code for saving armadillo matrices is in _include/armadillo_bits/diskio_meat.hpp_   For saving as ascii text, the corresponding functions are _diskio::save_raw_ascii()_.   Instead of spaces, perhaps the underlying standard C++ library (provided by the compiler) is using an incorrect padding character?

Comment: Thanks for all. I checked the diskio::save_raw_ascii(). It uses " std::ostream& f" and "f.put(' ');". I guess it does not have any problems, right? I think I need to test with this simple code on my friend's computer.